# Dojo iframe load is not called

Tags: iframe, dojo

Im uplaoding file to Amazon S3 using dojo.io.iframe.send:

```
            var d = dojo.io.iframe.send ({
                url: url,
                contentType: "multipart/form-data",
                method: "POST",
                form: this._form.domNode,
                handleAs: "text",

                load: dojo.hitch(this, function (respText) {
                    alert(1)
                    this.showLoading(false);
                    this.onSuccess(this.nodeFormName.value);
                }),
                error: dojo.hitch(this, function (err) {
                    console.log("err", err)
                    this.showError(err);
                })
            }, true);
```

I can see via using sniffer that file upload finished (and file is indeed in S3 bucket) but "load" or "error" callback functions are never called. Via sniffer I can see that response code is 204 "no content" and I assume that it may be root of the problem. Anyone had similar problem or know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. Since the only way for iframe to process result is to get  format, I added redirect header for successfull upload on Amazon S3. Redirecting now to static page in format success

Did the trick.